# How to separate a double integral function f(x,y)

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, generating-functions

So, I have integral function $f(x,y)=\int_{-2}^2\int_0^3\sqrt{(4-x^2)(9-y^2)}dydx$ that I want to solve.

Is there a more conventional (or correct, even) way of doing it than separating them as $\int_{-2}^2\sqrt{(4-x^2)}dx\int_{0}^3\sqrt{(9-y^2)}dy$,

because this right here generates a nasty integrals and I think they should generate a more fine mid-function answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a more conventional (or correct, even) way of doing it

No.

The way you started is perfectly fine and is the ideal way to do it anyway.  Why is it ideal?  Recall what a definite integral represents geometrically: area under a curve.

What does the graph of $y = \sqrt{4-x^2}$ look like?  It's the upper half of a circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin.  So what does $\displaystyle \int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx$ represent?

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Would it be unmathematical to just say "screw it" and calculate it as half the area of a circle with the diameter of 2 and the h(y) as quarter area of a circle with the radius 2? 

I'm asking this because the course I'm calculating these for is not reliant on calculators and even a little bit more complex functions like the functions I would get from integrating it would produce are uncommon

Comment: @Grak, nope, doing that is exactly what I was getting at.  Not only would I say it's *not* unmathematical, but doing it would demonstrate a solid understanding of how to interpret definite integrals and how to use an interpretation wisely.  Alternatively the integral is a routine, albeit relatively tedious, calculation that can be done with trig sub or with integration by parts.  There may be other ways but those are the two that I can immediately think of.

Comment: Note that $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables in the integral.  The integral gives a constant value.

Comment: @Grak, the $h(y)$ you're referring to is a quarter circle of radius $3$, not $2$.  Not sure if that was a typo but I didn't catch it until just now anyway.

Comment: It was a typo, but thanks for checking out anyway.